# Using Python and Selenium, how can I select all checkboxes contained within a DIV?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm trying to select all checkboxes from a consent page like so:

[image]

The element I'm trying to select is:

```
    <div class="tableCell rowBody headTitle">
        <span class="deskOnly">Email</span>
        <div class="ckeckAll">
            <input type="checkbox" id="allEmail" for="Email" class="allNone bigCheck cbChecked"
                value="true"><label for="allEmail" class="consentCheck"><span></span></label>
            <label for="allEmail" class="mobileOnly">Email</label>
            <div class="downArrow deskOnly" for="allEmail"></div>
            <ul id="menuEmail" for="allEmail"
                class="dropMenu ui-menu hoverMenu deskOnly ui-widget ui-widget-content" role="menu"
                tabindex="0" style="display: none;" aria-activedescendant="ui-id-1">
                <li class="All ui-menu-item">
                    <div id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"
                        class="ui-menu-item-wrapper menuText">All</div>
                </li>
                <li class="None ui-menu-item">
                    <div id="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"
                        class="ui-menu-item-wrapper menuText">None</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using a Select but got an error to say you can only use this with  elements, not  elements.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried and the error trace?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

```
allCheckbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='allEmail']")
allCheckbox.click()
```

If that doesn't work, use JS to perform `click()` as below:

```
allCheckbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='allEmail']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", allCheckbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) and an *`<input>`* element so using `Select()` won't work.

---

To click on on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#allEmail"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='allEmail']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

Incase the `<label>` overlaps the *`<input>`* element you can use either of the following ([Of the many findElement(s)/By functions in Selenium, when would you use one over the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over)):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='allEmail']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='allEmail']"))).click()
  ```